# iOS Facebook API fetch data from timeline using GRAPH API

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a facebook account. That account 'Liked' 3 open facebook pages. When you login to that facebook account from your browser you can ofcourse see all the posts from those 3 pages on your news feed.

What I want to know is - can I somehow fetch all the data I see on my accounts news feed?

Im not asking how to do it, just is it possible.
I was doing some research, and on facebook.developers they do mention about nodes, which can be users or groups, but it is unclear to me are those groups that I made, so when I login to my mobile app i Actually login with that group account, or they meant that I can get data or other groups out there ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has documentation using FQL queries to GET the users news feed, take a look here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql

What you are looking for is called stream...